# Notification "app started to the background"

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I published an app recently in a private environment and some users told me that sometimes a notification containing "app started to the background" is firing up.

The message **"app started to the background"** is meaningful. However, when I use my app on my iPhone and that the app starts from background, I don't have any notification fo this kind.

Do you know what could fire this up ?

This is a screenshot of a user who complained about it.

[image]

Comment: Is your app starting in the background?

Comment: The app can receive a VoipPushNotification which whould awake the application. However, I tested it a lot and I never saw this before!

Comment: That message is not correct English, therefore I hardly think such an ungrammatical message could be automatically generated by the OS. So are you absolutely 100% sure you do not have the phrase "App started to the background" anywhere in your code.

Comment: I didn't find this hardcoded string in my project but a `grep -Rn "App started to the background" .` matches a binary file of a library I use. I didn't expect that at all! The incorrect message should have set me on the right path, the binary in question have been made by Polish guys... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Essence of chicken](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1411070/essence-of-chicken) said, that couldn't be a message generated by the OS due to the grammatical errors on it.

It was due to an external library I use. A `Find in Workspace...` of "App started to the background" in my Xcode project didn't reveal anything. The only way to find where this string came from was with a `grep` (because the command search in binaries too):

```
➜  iOS_app git:(dev) ✗ grep -Rn "App started to the background" .
Binary file ./Frameworks/Softphone.framework/Softphone matches
```